# AS3 Signals: Is there a way to know when a signal has already dispatched?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, signals

I'm using Signals by Robert Penner in my latest project. It works great.

https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals

Now I need a way to know when a signal hal already been dispatched somewhere in the past. For example I have a class that dispatches a signal when it is fully loaded, but I need some flag in the same class to allow some methods to work only if the event has already been dispatched.

So, the quick and fast solution is to add a boolean in the event handler:

```
isLoaded = true;
```

But I wonder if there's already something implemented in the Signal class that I could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added RelaxedSignal classes to Penner's original ones. They haven't been merged into his codebase, and suspect they'll never will. I don't know why though, I've asked him several times, but he won't react.

Anyway, if you subscribe to a signal that has already been dispatched it will immediately call the listener for the subscriber. I created this especially for situations like yours, where you want to respond to an event that may or may not have already happened.

> Signals are great but there’s one feature that’s really missing: the ability to subscribe to a signal, after it has been dispatched.

Explanation: http://creynders.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/relaxedsignals/

Source: https://github.com/creynders/as3-signals

Example: https://github.com/creynders/RelaxedSignalsDemo

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. I'm sure it will be useful to other people too.

Comment: Do you have an SWC file with your branch of Signals?

Comment: No, I don't. Do you have problems compiling from the source?

Comment: No... I suppose I could do it with Flash Builder, but I never got into  using Flex.

Comment: You don't necessarily need FB, you can just add them to your own source files and compile them together with whatever compiler/IDE you're using. I'll see if I got the time to create a .swc today, though.

Comment: You can find the .swc here: https://github.com/creynders/as3-signals/downloads
It includes v0.9-BETA of the original Signals

Comment: Thanks again! I'll integrate it in my current project asap!

Answer (score 1):

I think you would add a boolean to your class, I think you should not make this dependent to the signal, cause maybe you would later change it to normal events and then your screwed. An `isLoaded` boolean should be part of a loader, not a signal/event.

Comment: True, the isLoaded boolean should be part of the loading class. But that is an example. Is there a way to know when an event was already dispatched in the Signals library?